# If my site worked with ie6 standards, is there a doctype that will make ie8 act it is ie6?

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser, ie8-compatibility-mode

I guess this might be a miracle, but is there a way to make the doctype of tell ie8 to treat the html just like it would in ie6 standards mode.  I know you can make ie8 do ie7 standards mode, and I think you can do ie6 quirks mode from ie8, but is there a way to do ie6 standards mode from ie8?

Thanks,
Grae

Comment: By the way, I know ie6 is old, but the component I use are designed for ie6, so not all of them work on ie8.  There is kind of no way around that problem.

Comment: Time to upgrade the components that are using technology that is 10 years old. Do you still program on machines that are 10 years old? :) Hard business sell, but think you will have IE9 coming up soon. Plus what about mobile devices and other browsers? Fixing it for IE8 means it will work on those. Win-Win.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, there isn't.

The `X-UA-Compatible` tag offers an option to emulate IE 5 (WTF?) and 7, but not 6.

Reference: [Understanding Compatibility Modes in Internet Explorer 8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/askie/understanding-compatibility-modes-in-internet-explorer-8)

The best option is probably to fix the components you are using.

Comment: IE5 is there for a good reason: it's the rendering used for Quirks Mode.

Comment: This is terrible.  I have one component that works in ie8 standards mode, and one that wirks in ie7 standards.

Comment: @Grae I think you need to fix the components, using compatibility view is going to cause other problems

Comment: Turns out everything seems to work in ie8 quirks mode, which I guess in practice must be somewhat like ie6 standards mode.